# Capistrano deploy:start with unicorn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

Deploying with capistrano. 
Everything goes fine, and then while deploy:start (during deploy:cold), it produces an error:

```
  * ←[32m2013-03-14 15:03:05 executing `deploy:start'←[0m
  * ←[33mexecuting "/etc/init.d/unicorn_appname start"←[0m
    servers: ["XXX.XXX.131.4"]
    [XXX.XXX.131.4] executing command
 ** [out :: XXX.XXX.131.4] sh: /etc/init.d/unicorn_appname: not found
    ←[2;37mcommand finished in 1572ms←[0m
failed: "sh -c '/etc/init.d/unicorn_appname start'" on XXX.XXX.131.4
```

The file in question exists. Here's it's contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          unicorn
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Manage unicorn server
# Description:       Start, stop, restart unicorn server for a specific application.
### END INIT INFO
set -e

# Feel free to change any of the following variables for your app:
TIMEOUT=${TIMEOUT-60}
APP_ROOT=/root/apps/appname/current
PID=$APP_ROOT/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid
CMD="cd $APP_ROOT; bundle exec unicorn -D -c $APP_ROOT/config/unicorn.rb -E production"
AS_USER=root
set -u

OLD_PIN="$PID.oldbin"

sig () {
  test -s "$PID" && kill -$1 `cat $PID`
}

oldsig () {
  test -s $OLD_PIN && kill -$1 `cat $OLD_PIN`
}

run () {
  if [ "$(id -un)" = "$AS_USER" ]; then
    eval $1
  else
    su -c "$1" - $AS_USER
  fi
}

case "$1" in
start)
  sig 0 && echo >&2 "Already running" && exit 0
  run "$CMD"
  ;;
stop)
  sig QUIT && exit 0
  echo >&2 "Not running"
  ;;
force-stop)
  sig TERM && exit 0
  echo >&2 "Not running"
  ;;
restart|reload)
  sig HUP && echo reloaded OK && exit 0
  echo >&2 "Couldn't reload, starting '$CMD' instead"
  run "$CMD"
  ;;
upgrade)
  if sig USR2 && sleep 2 && sig 0 && oldsig QUIT
  then
    n=$TIMEOUT
    while test -s $OLD_PIN && test $n -ge 0
    do
      printf '.' && sleep 1 && n=$(( $n - 1 ))
    done
    echo

    if test $n -lt 0 && test -s $OLD_PIN
    then
      echo >&2 "$OLD_PIN still exists after $TIMEOUT seconds"
      exit 1
    fi
    exit 0
  fi
  echo >&2 "Couldn't upgrade, starting '$CMD' instead"
  run "$CMD"
  ;;
reopen-logs)
  sig USR1
  ;;
*)
  echo >&2 "Usage: $0 <start|stop|restart|upgrade|force-stop|reopen-logs>"
  exit 1
  ;;
esac
```

Having tried to run the command through ssh (sh -c '/etc/init.d/unicorn_appname start'), I've encountered the same error.

What can be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for the suggestions.
The problem is finally solved.
The issue turned out to be with deployment from a windows machine - .sh file had Windows-styled line endings and could not be correctly read by unix.
The solution was in changing IDE settings accordingly (for Rubymine: File->Settings->Code style->General->Line separator->unix) and recreating the file. Then:
git add .
git commit -m "fix"
git push
cap deploy:setup
cap deploy:cold

Done!
Thanks again eveybody!

P.S.: does anybody know why can asset pipeline not work after deployment?

Comment: They say nothing. Assets simply do not load. For example, no css is used except embedded.

Comment: Do you have load 'assets/deploy'  in your Capfile?

Comment: @cmaitchison No, I have `load 'deploy/assets'` instead.RubyMine underlines it and says there's no such file to load. I've tried to change it to `load 'assets/deploy'`, but then `cap deploy` gave me an error there's no such file instead.

Comment: sorry, I meant 'deploy/assets'. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Could you tell what is the file `/etc/init.d/unicorn_appname`? I didn's see it created in the railscast. How is it created?

Comment: https://coderwall.com/p/yz8cha/deploying-rails-app-using-nginx-unicorn-postgres-and-capistrano-to-digital-ocean

Answer (score 1):

This most probably occurs if you have symlinked from the relative path vs absolute path. Try to symlink again by providing the absolute path.

`chmod +x /home/username/app/app_name/current/config/unicorn_init.sh`

`ln -nfs /home/username/app/app_name/current/config/unicorn_init.sh /etc/init.d/unicorn_app_name`

And see if this works

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tried it, doesn't work. Doesn't even change any output. Should the commands you mention provide any output, by the way?

Comment: Just asking.. did you try symlink using `sudo`?

Comment: Yes, I have. And in the deploy.rb it's also written like this: `sudo "ln -nfs #{current_path}/config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/#{application}"` `sudo "ln -nfs #{current_path}/config/unicorn_init.sh /etc/init.d/unicorn_#{application}"`

Comment: The link does exist, by the way. Here's the result of ls -l: `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   51 2013-03-15 01:05 unicorn_appname -> /root/apps/appname/current/config/unicorn_init.sh`

Answer (score 0):

Your capistrano deploy:start task should read

```
task :start, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
  run "/etc/init.d/unicorn start"
end
```

Unless you deliberately named your unicorn init file /etc/init.d/unicorn_appname.

Does the capistrano deploy user have execute permission on that file?

Comment: It is named so. The task reads like this:
`%w[start stop restart].each do |command| (/n)
  desc "#{command} unicorn server" (/n)
  task command, roles: :app, except: {no_release: true} do (/n)
    run "/etc/init.d/unicorn_#{application} #{command}" (/n)
  end (/n)
end`

Comment: Does '/etc/init.d/unicorn_appname start' work when you run it while sshd in as the capistrano deploy user? Or does it also give an error?

Comment: It doesn't work and it does also give the same error: `sh: /etc/init.d/unicorn_appname: not found`