# Ruby on Rails: Unicorn failed to start server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, unicorn

I'm following [#335 Deploying to a VPS](http://railscasts.com/episodes/335-deploying-to-a-vps?view=comments), and when I run `cap deploy:cold`, everthing goes fine except at the end it reports

```
executing 'deploy:start'
executing "/etc/init.d/unicorn_just4magic start"
servers: ["106.XXX.XXX.XXX"]
[106.XXX.XXX.XXX] executing command
out :: 106.XXX.XXX.XXX sh: /etc/init.d/unicorn_just4magic: Permission denied
command finished in 502ms
failed: "env PATH=$HOME/.rbenv/shims:$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH sh -c '/etc/init.d/unicorn_just4magic start'" on 
106.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

I can run `rails server` manually on VPS, and has no problem at all.
But when using cap to deploy, I get the above error. When I visit my site I get `Sorry Something went wrong` prompt

UPDATE:
deploy.rb is [here](https://github.com/railscasts/335-deploying-to-a-vps/blob/master/blog-nginx/config/deploy.rb), and here is the `start/restart` part

```
  %w[start stop restart].each do |command|
    desc "#{command} unicorn server"
    task command, roles: :app, except: {no_release: true} do
      run "/etc/init.d/unicorn_#{application} #{command}"
    end
  end
```

UPDATE2:
now the `permission denied` prompt does not appear, and I get another problem:
`sudo: /etc/init.d/unicorn_just4magic: command not found`

I find [Capistrano deploy:start with unicorn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15408105/capistrano-deploystart-with-unicorn) and [During cap deploy:cold - command not found for /etc/init.d/unicorn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16199654/during-cap-deploycold-command-not-found-for-etc-init-d-unicorn)
I changed the line separator of the shell script, and remove the `gemfile.lock` from git and  `set :bundle_flags, ''`. Still get the error

Comment: deploy.rb can you please put it? it wants sudo user permission

Comment: make it `run "#{sudo :as => 'cqcn'} /etc/init.d/unicorn_#{application} #{command}"` or `run "#{sudo} /etc/init.d/unicorn_#{application} #{command}"`

Comment: @RajarshiDas It is now working. But I get `command not found` error. please see my update2

Comment: hi sorry for late......command not found?

Comment: I can give you a simple suggestion rathe  than doing all complex command just use `run "unicorn_rails"`

Comment: @RajarshiDas What does that mean? run it in the vps like `rails sever`?

Comment: your run should be like `#{sudo} run "/etc/init.d/unicorn_rails"`

Comment: Well...I get `sh: /etc/init.d/unicorn_rails: not found`. Am I missing something? What need to be installed?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by giving the local file /config/unicorn_init.sh executable permissions by running `chmod +x config/unicorn_init.sh` on it. Push it to your git repo, cap deploy to server and it worked like a charm for me.

It seems that it does not play well to fiddle with the permissions on the server.

Also, if you can't seem to find the file as you describe ("command not found"), try running a `cap deploy:setup` once more with the new permissions and go from there. Might be the case that the symlink is not created correctly due to the permission problem?

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

By default Unix user has permissions on its /home/user/ directory
File `unicorn_just4magic` is not under home direcotry or any allowed to write directory thus you get the "Permission demied" error.
**To solve the issue you can**:
- Move `unicorn_just4magic` somewhere under your home directory (*this you can set in your unicorn config file*)
OR
- add permission on /etc/ directory for your user
`$ chown your_username /etc/init.d/unicorn_just4magic`

Comment: It works. But now I get `command not found error`. How to deal with this?

Comment: When you run `chown your_username /etc/init.d/unicorn_just4magic` ?

Comment: When I run cap deploy:start, which fail to run `/etc/init.d/unicorn_just4magic start`. See my UPDATE in the problem